# How to calculate mean per group from list of data.tables?

Tags: r, list, optimization, data.table, rbindlist

Let's say we have a list of `data.table`'s like this:

```
dt <- data.table(x=rnorm(10^6,100,10), letters=sample(LETTERS,10^6,T))
myList <- list(dt1=dt,dt2=dt,dt3=dt,dt4=dt,dt5=dt)
```

If I wanted a solution that would calculate the mean per group across all data.tables, I could do the following:

```
bigDT <- rbindlist(myList)
bigDT[,list('average'=mean(x)),by=letters]
```

With my data, however, each `dt` is quite large (millions of rows) and each list is substantial as well (500-1000 `dt` in each list). There are also considerably more than two options for the `by` choice.

Part of a function I plan on optimizing using genetic algorithms requires computing the above mean by group. I was wondering if there was a more efficient solution than `rbind`-ing the list before using `data.table`'s ability to calculate per group? Otherwise, the maximization algorithm will makes many function calls to this potentially bottlenecking calculation.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
microbenchmark(doThis())
Unit: milliseconds
     expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 doThis() 151.512 154.3395 174.8071 167.7151 170.2952 440.9359   100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to computed the grouped means for each table within the list, then bind, then compute a [*weighted mean*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) of them. Since you have different counts of each letter, you'll need to preserve the `.N` as well.

I'm going to change each element of the list so that we can verify the weighted-mean calculations. For reproducibility:

```
set.seed(1)
myList <- replicate(5, data.table(x=rnorm(10^6,100,10), letters=sample(LETTERS,10^6,T)),
                    simplify=FALSE)
myList[1:2]
# [[1]]
#                  x letters
#       1:  93.73546       P
#       2: 101.83643       I
#       3:  91.64371       F
#       4: 115.95281       V
#       5: 103.29508       D
#      ---                  
#  999996: 109.24487       Q
#  999997:  99.86486       K
#  999998:  93.95941       J
#  999999: 116.28763       O
# 1000000: 106.93750       E
# [[2]]
#                  x letters
#       1:  97.53576       R
#       2: 105.27503       T
#       3: 107.53592       L
#       4: 102.21228       M
#       5:  98.71087       G
#      ---                  
#  999996: 109.46843       C
#  999997:  99.14458       M
#  999998:  96.76845       Y
#  999999:  94.22413       E
# 1000000:  98.25855       K
```

To do this for just one table:

```
head(myList[[1]][,.(mu = mean(x), n = .N), keyby=letters])
#    letters        mu     n
# 1:       A 100.04987 39005
# 2:       B 100.01288 38576
# 3:       C  99.97402 38547
# 4:       D  99.99909 38460
# 5:       E 100.03689 38030
# 6:       F 100.02697 38293
```

First, compute the averages per-list-element:

```
myAgg <- rbindlist(lapply(myList, function(d) d[,.(mu = mean(x), n = .N), keyby="letters"]))
```

Now do the weighted-mean either manually or with `Hmisc::wtd.mean`:

```
cbind(
  # just to verify the below answer is the same as the brute-force method of rbind-then-average
  rbindlist(myList)[,.(mu = mean(x)), keyby=letters],
  # either of these is your answer
  myAgg[,.(mu = sum(n*mu)/sum(n)),keyby=letters],
  myAgg[,.(mu = Hmisc::wtd.mean(mu, weights=n)),keyby=letters]
)
#     letters        mu letters        mu letters        mu
#  1:       A 100.02325       A 100.02325       A 100.02325
#  2:       B 100.03473       B 100.03473       B 100.03473
#  3:       C 100.00688       C 100.00688       C 100.00688
#  4:       D 100.04041       D 100.04041       D 100.04041
#  5:       E 100.00780       E 100.00780       E 100.00780
#  6:       F 100.01202       F 100.01202       F 100.01202
#  7:       G 100.01200       G 100.01200       G 100.01200
#  8:       H  99.97232       H  99.97232       H  99.97232
#  9:       I 100.00495       I 100.00495       I 100.00495
# 10:       J 100.03019       J 100.03019       J 100.03019
# 11:       K  99.96851       K  99.96851       K  99.96851
# 12:       L 100.01850       L 100.01850       L 100.01850
# 13:       M 100.00976       M 100.00976       M 100.00976
# 14:       N 100.01299       N 100.01299       N 100.01299
# 15:       O 100.02108       O 100.02108       O 100.02108
# 16:       P 100.02052       P 100.02052       P 100.02052
# 17:       Q 100.03814       Q 100.03814       Q 100.03814
# 18:       R  99.99013       R  99.99013       R  99.99013
# 19:       S  99.95219       S  99.95219       S  99.95219
# 20:       T  99.97721       T  99.97721       T  99.97721
# 21:       U  99.96310       U  99.96310       U  99.96310
# 22:       V  99.94430       V  99.94430       V  99.94430
# 23:       W  99.98877       W  99.98877       W  99.98877
# 24:       X 100.07352       X 100.07352       X 100.07352
# 25:       Y  99.96677       Y  99.96677       Y  99.96677
# 26:       Z  99.99397       Z  99.99397       Z  99.99397
#     letters        mu letters        mu letters        mu
```

Quick benchmarking, for comparison:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  bruteforce = rbindlist(myList)[,.(mu = mean(x)), keyby=letters],
  # either of these is your answer
  baseR = {
    myAgg <- rbindlist(lapply(myList, function(d) d[,.(mu = mean(x), n = .N), keyby="letters"]))
    myAgg[,.(mu = sum(n*mu)/sum(n)),keyby=letters]
  },
  Hmisc =  {
    myAgg <- rbindlist(lapply(myList, function(d) d[,.(mu = mean(x), n = .N), keyby="letters"]))
    myAgg[,.(mu = Hmisc::wtd.mean(mu, weights=n)),keyby=letters]
  },
  times=50
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#  bruteforce 131.8770 139.4562 153.93202 151.95375 159.6329 315.6117    50
#       baseR  89.7047  93.3623 109.20174  98.11670 115.0171 268.2517    50
#       Hmisc  89.2784  91.5927  97.87455  93.73475  98.1655 119.2671    50
```

Comment: another possible approach: `rbindlist(lapply(myList, function(x) x[, .(sum(x), .N), .(letters), verbose=TRUE]))[, .(sum(V1), sum(N)), .(letters), verbose=TRUE][, MEAN := V1/V2]`